# How to add UIView subviews in a view aligned like 3x3 table

Tags: objective-c, uiview, core-animation, alignment, uiviewanimation

I have created a main View and in that I add 9 UIMyView that I subclassed from UIView.
I add instances of that UIMyViews using NSBundle to load the nib file and addSubview in the main view controller, of course all of these views are appeared in the upper left corner of the super view one hiding the other and the last one to be visible, which either I need to position them somehow using points in super view or create something like a table and add to its cells the UIMyViews?!

Imagine you have a table and put 9 deck cards positioned 3 rows and 3 columns (9 cards).
This is what I need to achieve.

[EDIT]
Check this image: http://www.wpclipart.com/recreation/games/card_deck/cards_symbols/playing_card_symbols.png

I just need 3 rows and 3 columns.

Anyone can suggest best practice for this kind of operation?

Afterwards just to have in mind I want to implement various animations and effects on these UIMyViews while draged, touched and reordering etc.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking.

Comment: I mean I need to align 9 views in 3 rows on the iPhone screen.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see the image link! Its what I need on the screen only 3 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop through all the views and position them in a grid, you can so like this:

```
    // Array of 9 views    
NSArray *views = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)], nil];

int count = 0;
int maxPerRow = 3;
int row = 0;
float spacing = 100.0;

for(UIView *view in views)
{
    // Only added to tell the difference between views, make sure to import QuartzCore or remove the next 3 lines
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
    view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    // position view
    view.frame = CGRectMake(count*spacing, row * spacing, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:view];

    if(count % maxPerRow == maxPerRow-1)
    {
        count = 0;
        row++;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

That will give you something like this:

[image]

Comment: This was really perfect and so simple I couldn't figure out. Almost there though, I will fix, there is something going on with the position and aligned one row top to the half of the other. Thank you. Marked too...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add them all manually you just set the frame of each of the subviews prior to adding to the main view:

```
CustomView *view = [[CustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
```

There are "smarter" ways to approach this than setting everything manually. iOS6 contains some features for this and there's also gridviews made such as:

- [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView)
- [DTGridView](https://github.com/danielctull/DTGridView)
- [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

Comment: I already do this in super view's controller. But this way I have to calculate where to put the cards. Thanx for the reference on GridView. But I think I'll stick around with older practice because of the excercise I try to experiment.

Comment: I haven't created with initWithFrame but with NSBundle loadNibNamed. If I try to load with what you recomend, my view not appearing in the screen. Any idea?